# Сравнение элементов матрицы

Tags: python

Нужна помощь с поэлементным сравнением в матрице Для заданной матрицы размером 8 x 8 найти такие k, что элементы k-й строки матрицы совпадают с элементами k-ого столбца.

У меня ошибка в том что элементы сравнивает с учётом порядка,а надо без

```
from random import randint
n = 8
A = [[randint(1,2) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
out_2 = [0] * n
out_1 = ["p"] * n
temp_row = [0] * n
temp_col = []

for i in range(n):
    temp_col.append([0] * n)

for Row in range(n):
    for Col in range(n):
        print("{0:02}".format(A[Row][Col]), end=" ")
    print()

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        temp_col[i][j] = A[j][i]

for i in range(n):
    temp_row[i] = A[i]

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if temp_row[i] == temp_col[j]:
            out_1[i] = i

for i, (row, col) in enumerate(zip(A, zip(*A))):
    if sorted(row) == sorted(col):
        print(i+1,f"Ряд и колонка с индексом {i} полностью совпадают.")
    else:
        print(i+1,"Одинаковых строчек и столбцов в итерации ", i + 1, "не найдено")

for Row in range(n):
    for number in A[Row]:
        if number < 0:
            out_2[Row] = sum(A[Row])
```

выводит

```
02 02 02 02 01 02 01 01 
02 02 01 02 02 02 02 02 
02 01 01 01 02 02 01 01 
01 01 02 02 02 02 02 02 
01 01 01 02 01 01 01 01 
02 01 01 01 01 02 02 02 
01 01 01 02 02 02 02 02 
02 01 01 01 02 01 02 02 
1 Ряд и колонка с индексом 0 полностью совпадают.
2 Одинаковых строчек и столбцов в итерации  2 не найдено
3 Одинаковых строчек и столбцов в итерации  3 не найдено
4 Одинаковых строчек и столбцов в итерации  4 не найдено
5 Одинаковых строчек и столбцов в итерации  5 не найдено
6 Одинаковых строчек и столбцов в итерации  6 не найдено
7 Ряд и колонка с индексом 6 полностью совпадают.
8 Одинаковых строчек и столбцов в итерации  8 не найдено
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Исправил,нужно,чтобы не взирая на порядок сравнивало

Comment: Сделайте из строк и столбцов сортированные списки, и сравнивайте их

Answer (score 1):

Просто отсортируйте значения ряда и колонки прежде чем их сравнивать.

```
for i, (row, col) in enumerate(zip(A, zip(*A))):
    if sorted(row) == sorted(col):
        print(f"Ряд и колонка с индексами {i} полностью совпадают.")
```

Здесь `zip(*A)` транспонирует матрицу (т.е. её столбцы становятся рядами). Далее следующим `zip` берутся одновременно ряд из исходной матрицы и ряд из транспонированной (он же столбец из исходной). Ну и в `enumerate` обёрнуто, чтобы считать номер ряда/столбца).

Comment: он почему-то учитывает порядок(

Comment: спасибо большое,но нужно поэлементное сравнение,а тут сразу весь ряд и колонку

Comment: @DongoCongo Покажите маленький пример строки и столбца

Comment: `
02 02 02 02 01 02 01 01 

02 02 01 02 02 02 02 02 

02 01 01 01 02 02 01 01 

01 01 02 02 02 02 02 02 

01 01 01 02 01 01 01 01 

02 01 01 01 01 02 02 02 
01 01 01 02 02 02 02 02 
02 01 01 01 02 01 02 02 
1 Ряд и колонка с индексом 0 полностью совпадают.
2 Одинаковых строчек и столбцов в итерации  2 не найдено
3 Одинаковых строчек и столбцов в итерации  3 не найдено
4 Одинаковых строчек и столбцов в итерации  4 не найдено
5 Одинаковых строчек и столбцов в итерации  5 не найдено
6 Одинаковых строчек и столбцов в итерации  6 не найден `

Comment: Да не надо этой простыни. Пример строки из 4 значений и столбца также, и покажите, что по-вашему, является совпадением

Comment: отредактировал вопрос и там пример вывода в итерации 4 нужно сравнить элемент 02 со всем столбцом и тогда он найдёт ещё один 02 и выведет совпадение

Comment: спасибо большое,что помогаете

Comment: все,поправил,спасибо

Comment: @DongoCongo 4 ряд с 4 столбцом (нумерация с единицы) никак не могут совпасть. В 4 столбце 3 единицы, а в 4 ом ряду только 2 единицы. И вообще, что за строки и столбцы в "итерации"? Сравниваются элементы (значения) этих строк и столбцов.